# npm import from same index.js that the current file is exported from

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, importerror

Suppose I have created an npm module named `@myscope/blurfl` that contains a couple of classes: A, defined in `A.js` and B defined in `B.js`, that are both re-exported through `blurfl/index.js`:

```
@myscope/
    blurfl/
        A.js
        B.js
        index.js
```

A.js:

```
export class A {...}
```

B.js:

```
import { A } from './A.js';
export class B {...}
```

index.js:

```
export * from "./A.js";
export * from "./B.js";
```

I would prefer to use `import { A } from '@myscope/blurfl'` instead of `import {A} from './A.js'` to keep the code cleaner (and make it easier to move an export into a different file), but `@myscope/blurfl` is obviously not a dependency of `@myscope/blurfl` itself, so the node module resolver can't find it if I run `node index.js` to check for missing dependencies.

Is there any way to import another item co-exported from the same index.js file without using the item's explicit filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using a current version of Node.js (12 LTS or later).
Make sure that the `"name"` of your package in package.json is really `"@myscope/blurfl"` (and not just `"blurfl"`).
Now, add an `"exports"` section to the package.json specifying the relative path of the main export, i.e.

```json
"exports": {
    ".": "./index.js"
}
```

You should now be able to use `import { A } from '@myscope/blurfl'` from within your package, too.

So, to summarize:

- Use Node 12 or later.
- Check the `"name"` in package.json.
- Add an `"exports"` section to package.json indicating the [main entry point export](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#main-entry-point-export).

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to try this out!